# Map characters a strings into dictionary with index as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i am new in python coding, I am trying to map characters a strings into dictionary with index as key.
I'm using a string "asleep" and want to get output as

```
{0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'l', 3: 'e', 4: 'e', 5: 'p'}
```

I'm using the following code:

```
myWord = "asleep"

char_count = map(lambda x: dict(enumerate(x)), myWord)

print(char_count)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 's': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 2, 'p': 1}
```

Comment: Why do you want to this though? I don't see any viable reason to doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution:

```py
>>> word = 'asleep'
>>> dict(enumerate(word))
{0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'l', 3: 'e', 4: 'e', 5: 'p'}
```

This works because `enumerate` returns an iterable of pairs like `(0, 'a')`, `(1, 's')`, and so on; and the `dict` constructor works with an iterable of (key, value) pairs.

Comment: I was doing `{idx:char for idx, char in enumerate(myWord)}`, but this is even better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following line:

```
dict(zip(range(len(myWord)), myWord))
```